# Inject another page using java script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a need to inject some data which is present in another page(url) on the current page load. Below is the code I am using.But it doesnt work, is there is a problem with below code and how can I debug this issue?

```
function loadHTML(url, storage)
{
    var xhr = createXHR();
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    { 
        if(xhr.readyState == 4)
        {
            //if(xhr.status == 200)
            {
                storage.innerHTML = getBody(xhr.responseText);
            }
        } 
    }; 

    xhr.open("GET", url , true);
    xhr.send(null); 

} 


function loadWholePage(url)
{
    /**
        storage is the div id where I want to inject html
    */
    var y = document.getElementById("storage");
    loadHTML(url, y);
}   


window.onload = function()
{
   loadWholePage('link_to_the_page') ;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit a cross domain scripting problem. See [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

As far as I know, [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) can help you on this problem.

JSONP([JSON with Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)) provides a method to request data from a server in a different domain, something prohibited by typical web browsers because of the same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

There might be some issue with your function createXHR() and getBody(). Post the code you have written for those function. Moreover for debugging, you can put a console.log before calling getBody() and check what is responseText.

```
if(xhr.readyState == 4)
{
if(xhr.status == 200)
{
console.log(xhr.responseText);
storage.innerHTML = getBody(xhr.responseText);
}
}
```